# xmlreader traversing nodes

Tags: asp.net, .net, xmlreader

I have an xml file as follows,

```
<rss> 
  <report name="rpt1"> 
    <title>AAA</title> 
    <image/> 
    <weblink/> 
    <pdflink/> 
    <pdfsize/>
  </report> 
  <report name="rpt2"> 
    <title>BBB</title> 
    <image/> 
    <weblink/> 
    <pdflink/> 
    <pdfsize/>
  </report> 
</rss>
```

I have to traverse the link and go to report nodes and get the title/image/weblink/pdflink/pdfsize for each reports. How can I do that using xml reader. I google and see traversing for a single node but not in loop. Any inputs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**LINQtoXML**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to get the items from yout XML.

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/pairs.xml");    
XElement elm = XElement.Load(path);
//you can also load the XML from stream / string also

if (elm != null)
{
    foreach (var item in elm.Elements("report"))
    {
        string title = item.Element("title").Value;
        string image = item.Element("image").Value;
        string weblink= item.Element("weblink").Value;
        //do whatever with the values          
    }
}
```